# How to regain smooth shape whilst scaling a group of edges that contain both creased and non creased edges?

Tags: modeling, edges, subdivision-surface

I'm relatively new to Blender (self taught using these forums) but I've encountered a problem I can't seem to solve.

On the image below I've tried modeling a sliding button, and applied a Subsurf modifier to smoothen it, to keep the bottom part planar I've set the edge crease of the edges seen purple to 1.

[image]

Now I'd like to make the exterior ends of the button thinner than the middle part (as seen in the failed attempt). I did this by scaling the X axis of the region I wanted slimmer.
[image: Object mode after scale X]

I've tried solving it by replacing my creased egdes by egde loops close to eachother but got somewhat of the same result. How do I scale a group of edges of wich some are creased and some are not without distorting my overall shape ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I tried uploading more images but it seems i need more "reputation" for that, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

It seems i've solved my own problem after more struggeling. The culprit was me in the end, that went for a crappy geometry (the triangles and such) once i started over clean keeping everything planar until the last steps, the isues were no more. the lesson at the end of the day was; go for squares, not triangles :D.